# win xp client, win 7 host, only xp drivers

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have a win 7 64 bit box which has xp on it in a vmware module and also the win7 version. I can use my old usb wifi card under virtual xp as i have the wifi drivers, but apparently the manufacturing company never made any further drivers, nor did it release the source code.

Is it possible to get networking between the client and the host, so that my host can browse etc? I thought the microsoft loopback adapter might be the answer but ever example i can find of it's use describes a setup where the host is connected fine and needs to route data to the client as well.

Comment: Have you checked if there are drivers by the manufacturer of the WiFi chip itself? Usually the manufacturers of USB WiFi devices just provide a modified driver from the WiFi chip manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

Pass the wifi card via usb redirect then add a virtual NIC to the VM.

Then you'll want to set up internet connection sharing inside the XP VM, sharing from the wifi to the virtual ethernet adapter, then make sure the adapter is set to bridged mode and see if this will give you connectivity.

This is untested so no guarantees but it might work.

N.B. if bridged doesn't work for whatever reason try host-only networking, if Virtual PC supports it, I know VmWare Workstation does.